# How to show this affine algebraic set has dimension 3

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X:=V\left(x_0 x_1-x_2 x_3\right) \subset \mathbb{A}^4$. Show that $X$ has dimension 3.

So I am very new to algebraic geometry and I find the concept of dimension a little confusing. So I know from a theorem/lemma that the topological dimension of the set $X$ should be the same as the Krull dimension of the ring $K[X]$, but I am not sure if this makes things easier.

I have not formally studied commutative algebra, but the notes I currently reading just states them and assume you can use any results from commutative algebra, and in this chapter, Krull's dimension theorem was given. Ok but with all this, I am just not sure how to calculate the dimension since the definition is defined to be the supremum of all chains of prime ideals.

Answer (score 1):

The topological dimension of $X$ corresponds to the Krull dimension of the ring $k[x_0,\dots,x_3]/(x_0x_1-x_2x_3)$. By krull's principal ideal theorem, $\operatorname{ht}((x_0x_1-x_2x_3))\le 1$. Since $(x_0x_1-x_2x_3)$ is itself prime and nonzero, $\operatorname{ht}((x_0x_1-x_2x_3))= 1$.

On the other hand, for any finitely generated integral domain $A$ over a field and any prime $\mathfrak{p}$, we have $\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak{p})+\operatorname{dim}(A/\mathfrak{p})=\operatorname{dim}A$. In particular, $\operatorname{ht}((x_0x_1-x_2x_3))+\operatorname{dim}(k[x_0,\dots,x_3]/(x_0x_1-x_2x_3))=\operatorname{dim}k[x_0,\dots,x_3]=4$ so that $\operatorname{dim}(k[x_0,\dots,x_3]/(x_0x_1-x_2x_3))=4-1=3$.